# Explicación: Comunicación cliente android con la Servidor en Firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

me gustaría conocer como interactua una aplicacion android con la plataforma Firebase a nivel interno.

He estado leyendo  la documentacion pero no encuentro nada que me lo deje claro.
Se que se añaden los SDK de firebase al proyecto android, se añaden las librerias que te proporciona firebase para usar los distintos servicios como es el de autentificacion de usuario , cloud firestore etc...
Ahora bien, no se si internamente al dar de alta tu aplicacion en tu proyecto firebase se autoconfiguran los servidores web para realizar las consultas desde la aplicacion android o si bien en esta plataforma no se hace uso de servicios web, si no que usamos las librerias para acceder directamente al servicio proporcionado por firebase.

He realizado diferentes proyectos en casa usando Firestore funcionando todo correctamente pero realmente sin saber como funciona...

Obteniendo una instancia de la base de datos, obteninedo una referencia a la localizacion donde se queire escribir o leer, hacendo eso hago de todo pero sin realmente saber que se esta cociendo internamente...

Saludos .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mira a Firebase como una rest API basicamente donde haces consultas, tienen distintos modulos, donde obviamente todo es muy diferente.

Para poblar datos en la base, solo usas una referencia de donde queres poner los datos y con un `setValue` haces como un **POST** a la base de datos, con el `addValueEventListener` haces un **GET** en tiempo real de lo que se cambia (escucha activa) , con un `singleValueEventListener` haces tambien otro **GET** pero solo una vez y no queda escuchando como el anterior.

La conexion de Firebase con una app en android se hace mediante el archivo `google-services.json` que te hace configurar en la web o desde el mismo android studio para conectarte a un proyecto, este archivo tiene todas las configuraciones , ya sea el id de tu proyecto , como otros datos necesarios para conectarse con Firebase.

Cuando vos configuras este archivo, ingresas el SHA-1 de tu computadora, lo que genera una comunicación a Firebase donde solo vos podes escribir y leer estando en modo DEBUG, luego, deberas actualizar esa clave para produccion, esto no aplica a la app en si, sino como un medio de proteger que donde llegue tu `google-services.json` no pueda ser reutilizado por otra persona con otra instancia de Android Studio, basicamente es como un permiso que le das a Firebase para trabajar con tu proyecto.

Las reglas de firebase, para poblar datos **NO** son filtros, podes verlo como triggers en mysql, donde si ocurre tal condición, se dispara esa regla. Pero no lo veas como una forma de filtrar datos

[Reglas no son filtros](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#rules_are_not_filters)

Como dice en la documentación, podes darte una idea con que protoclos trabaja la autenticacion de usuarios

> Firebase Authentication se integra estrechamente en otros servicios de
>   Firebase y aprovecha los estándares de la industria como OAuth 2.0 y
>   OpenID Connect, por lo que se puede integrar fácilmente con tu backend
>   personalizado.

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración jejeje me ha resultado bastante util jejeje he realizado una aplicacion para un proyecto de fin de estudios y ponerme a documentar digo realmente ¿ que hay detras de todo ?
Entonces realmente al hacer un set, la aplicacion androd se comunica con lso servicios rest de Firebase y estos servicios con los modulos pertinentes